# Parse a ECC private key buffer

Tags: mbedtls, op-tee

I am using OPTEE-OS and mbedTLS and want to create a CSR. I am creating my EC key using the Global Platform API:

```
res = TEE_AllocateTransientObject(
    TEE_TYPE_ECDSA_KEYPAIR,
    DSEC_ECDSA_SHA256_KEY_BITS,
    &key_pair);
if (res != TEE_SUCCESS) {
    return res;
}
```

Then extract the private key:

```
res = TEE_GetObjectBufferAttribute(
    key_pair,
    TEE_ATTR_ECC_PRIVATE_VALUE,
    buffer,
    &bufferlen);
if (res != TEE_SUCCESS) {
    return res;
}
```

Then use mbedTLS to parse this value and create a to create a CSR:

```
mbedtls_pk_context priv_key;
mbedtls_pk_init(&priv_key);

ret = mbedtls_pk_parse_key(
    &priv_key,
    key,
    size,
    NULL ,
    0
  );
```

However, the extracted value from TEE_GetObjectBufferAttribute does not have the headers and footpage:

```
"-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----"
"-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

and is only a binary array (not a string). I am currently getting the following error code: `"-15616: PK - Invalid key tag or value".`

Is there any way to create a `mbedtls_pk_context` with only the binary value of my private key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parsing functions in Mbed TLS's `pk.h` expect DER or PEM input. If you can find ready-made code to export a key as DER (or PEM) from OPTEE, that'll be easier (but possibly marginally less efficient). On the other hand, it's easier to do the import manually than to write a DER export function.

You need to call [`mbedtls_pk_setup()`](https://tls.mbed.org/api/pk_8h.html#a7d6cc2c1768cc6db883b08c3c0f10889) to declare that the context will contain an ECC key, then build the ECC key directly using the interface in `ecp.h`. Convert the curve designation from the TEE encoding to the Mbed TLS encoding, and calculate the public key from the private value. (Alternatively, you could export `TEE_ATTR_ECC_PUBLIC_VALUE` and set `ec->Q`, but that's more work.)

```c
mbedtls_ecp_grp_id grp_id = …; // you need to convert this from the `TEE_ATTR_ECC_CURVE`
mbedtls_pk_context pk;
mbedtls_ecp_keypair *ec = malloc(sizeof(mbedtls_ecp_keypair));
mbedtls_pk_init(&pk);
mbedtls_pk_setup(&pk, mbedtls_pk_info_from_type(MBEDTLS_PK_ECDSA));
mbedtls_ecp_keypair_init(ec);
mbedtls_ecp_group_load(&ec->grp, grp_id);
mbedtls_mpi_read_binary(&ec->d, buffer, bufferlen);
mbedtls_ecp_check_privkey(&ec->grp, &ec->d);
mbedtls_ecp_mul(&ec->grp, &ec->Q, &ec->d, &ec->grp.G, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &ctr_drbg);
pk->pk_ctx = ec;
```

Completely untested. Error checking omitted. `ctr_drbg` is a CTR_DRBG instance, used for blinding during the calculation of the public key.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer here is the code to import Q if there are X and Y available as buffers. And I guess those are available since in order to create an ECDSA key in OPTEE using GlobalPlatform crypto API all 4 attributes (TEE_ATTR_xxx) are required (d, Q(X,Y) and the curve id)

```
rc = mbedtls_mpi_read_binary(&ec->Q.X, buffer_x, buffer_x_size);
rc = mbedtls_mpi_read_binary(&ec->Q.Y, buffer_y, buffer_y_size);
rc = mbedtls_mpi_lset(&ec->Q.Z, 1);
rc = mbedtls_ecp_check_pubkey(&ec->grp, &ec->Q);
```